# When I swipe from left to right, I don't want it to exit the wearos application in flutter

Tags: flutter, wear-os

When I swipe from left to right, I don't want it to exit the wearos application (in flutter/wearos). What can I do for this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

actually, this path writes for kotlin and java in androiddevelopers but l can't see for flutter. so l wrote it for flutter. almost everything is same.
you should open styles.xml(android/app/src/main/res/values/styles.xml).Then you should write  false this in Launch theme.
so it should looks like this

```
<style name="LaunchTheme" parent="@android:style/Theme.Light.NoTitleBar">
        <!-- Show a splash screen on the activity. Automatically removed when
             Flutter draws its first frame -->
        <item name="android:windowBackground">@drawable/launch_background</item>
        <item name="android:windowSwipeToDismiss">false</item>
    </style>
```